# Working with INTERVAL and CURDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, intervals

I'm building a chart and I want to receive data for each month.

Here's my first request which is working:

```
SELECT s.GSP_nom AS nom, timestamp, AVG( v.vote +  v.prix  ) /2 AS avg
FROM votes_serveur AS v
INNER JOIN serveur AS s ON v.idServ = s.idServ
WHERE s.valide =1
AND v.date > CURDATE() -30
GROUP BY s.GSP_nom
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

But, in my case I've to write 12 request to receive data for the 12 previous months, is there any trick to avoid writing:

```
//  example for the previous month
 AND v.date > CURDATE() -60
AND v.date < CURDATE () -30
```

I heard about INTERVAL, I went to the MySQL doc but i didn't manage to implement it.

Any example of using INTERVAL please?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need [`DATE_ADD/DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
AND v.date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
AND v.date < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

should work.

Answer (score 31):

As suggested by A Star, I always use something along the lines of:

```
DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Similarly you can do:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
"2013-01-01 00:00:00" + INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

and so on.  Much easier than typing `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` all the time :)!

Answer (score 17):

I usually use

```
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)
```

Which is almost same as Pekka's but this way you can control your INTERVAL to be negative or positive...

Comment: Sorry dude, yours don't work i don't know why mysql tells me that there is no results :/

Comment: Well, it should be:
AND v.date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)

Comment: I use `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`