# Monthly Dates In MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of trouble currently. The system I'm trying to implement is a 'callback' system that will set callbacks against customers that will pop up on the system at the specified date.

One of the features is a reoccurring callback. The two options are monthly and yearly. I have the yearly ones working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM `callbacks` WHERE (
-- Yearly Callbacks
(DAYOFYEAR(`date_callback`) = DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND `occurs` = 'yearly') OR

-- Other Callbacks For Today
(DATE(`date_callback`) = DATE(NOW())))
```

But I'm having trouble visualising how to check if a callback that is monthly is due. It should only occur once every 30 days in the list (that uses the above query.) I was using `DAYOFMONTH` but I realised that if a callback was set for the `31st` it wouldn't appear in the list for a few months at a time despite it being a monthly callback.

So if one is set for `March 3rd 2013` and set for montly, it should appear in the results of the query if the date is:

- `March 3rd 2013`
- `April 1st 2013`
- `May 1st 2013`
- `May 31st 2013`
- `June 30th 2013`

and so on. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider to use interval, something like

. . .
    (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
. . .

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793619/mysql-query-working-with-interval-and-curdate) post.

Or - you can try (pseudocode)

```
now() - pre_saved_date % 30 (module of 30)
```

For % - use MOD function, like

```
select MOD(2, 3);
select 3 % 2;
```

Comment: That's not really what I need. That'll only give me one month in advance. I need it so it will occur in that query if it is within a monthly period of the given date.

Comment: @andy - did you figure it out?