# select events with dates equal to or greater than one week from today?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a *calendar of events* table and I would like to select ALL events with dates equal to or greater than 2 weeks from `CURDATE()`. I have this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tournament_date_start, '%b %e') AS Tournament_Date
FROM tournament_main
WHERE tournament_main.tournament_date_start >= CURDATE()+14
ORDER BY tournament_main.tournament_date_start
LIMIT 5";
```

But it doesn't go two weeks ahead. I am not sure of how this works. Thanks!

Comment: What's the format of `tournament_date_start`?

Comment: What datatype are you using for tournament_date_start ?

Comment: Did you try:  `CURDATE() + interval 14 days`?

Comment: you'll find useful this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793619/mysql-query-working-with-interval-and-curdate

Comment: Success! Gordon-- I had the change "DAYS" to "DAY" and it worked. I found another line of questions that specified the use of DAY vs. DAYS and that did the trick!