# How to group by an interval of days

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a list of rows with a date format and a coinciding price ( just an example )

```
date     - price
01/01/14 - $5
01/02/14 - $5
01/03/14 - $1
01/10/14 - $1
01/12/14 - $2
```

I can successfully do a group by `date` with the following date alias

```
week(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%e/%Y')) AS `date`,
```

and get it to group by week according to MySQL.

What I need is to group by an interval of days, which will be defined from a user interface, ie 1,2,3,4,5,6 days.

My expected output would be

```html
    SELECT
     `date`,
     SUM`price`,
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY date range of 3 days
```

```
date - price
01/01/14 - 01/03/14 - $11
01/10/14 - 01/12/14 - $3
```

PROPOSED IDEA

EDIT - This will not work due to creating a new column for each instance. See Proposed idea #2

```sql
    WEEKOFYEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`ship date`, '%m/%e/%Y')) AS `woy`,
    WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(`ship date`, '%m/%e/%Y')) AS `wday`,

        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='0','range1', '') AS `range`,
        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='1','range1', '') AS `range`,
        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='2','range1', '') AS `range`,
        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='3','range2', '') AS `range`,
        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='4','range2', '') AS `range`,
        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='5','range2', '') AS `range`,
        IF ((SELECT `wday`)='6','range2', '') AS `range`,
```

PROPOSED IDEA #2

```sql
    `Ship Date`,
    WEEKOFYEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`ship date`, '%m/%e/%Y')) AS `woy`,
    WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(`ship date`, '%m/%e/%Y')) AS `wday`,

        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 0 THEN 'range1'
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 1 THEN 'range1'
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 2 THEN 'range1'
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 3 THEN 'range2'
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 4 THEN 'range2'
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 5 THEN 'range3'
            WHEN (SELECT `wday`) = 6 THEN 'range3'
        ELSE 'Other'
            END AS `range`,
```

Comment: Just store dates properly

Comment: The data is imported via .csv from a user interface, I'd like to dates to be imported and exported in that format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793619/working-with-interval-and-curdate-in-mysql hoping it will help you

Comment: Reformat them on import, and reformat them again export. It will be quicker.

Comment: I can group by week, month, dayofyear, year just fine with this date format using str_to_date. 

I've tired using the date_sub but I just can't figure out how to use it. I don't believe using today() is relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extra column defining which "grouping" it should belong to (see eg [In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)), perhaps using a case statement depending on what logic you need (see for eg [How does MySQL CASE work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389713/how-does-mysql-case-work))

```
SELECT GROUPING, SUM(PRICE) FROM 
    (SELECT
         DATE,
         PRICE,
{CASE statement for grouping logic} GROUPING
        FROM table)
        GROUP BY grouping
```

Comment: I could see this working, but for dayofyear I'd have to define a case statement for each interval of grouping wouldn't I? ie 1-3, 4-7-8-10, etc.

Comment: Maybe you need to generate a table to help, where you define the groupings you want to use? Also, analytic functions may help too: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

Comment: Believe that's what I'm going to end up doing, or perhaps a case situation basically saying if date is this day of the week, group by day of the week, and range.

Comment: Added a proposed idea. Grab week of year #, and week day #.. then define a range based upon week day # to allow me to group by week #, AND day of week #.

Comment: Nvm that won't work without nesting the IFs, perhaps a Case would be much better.