# SQL - How to get a range of timestamps using BETWEEN (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

So for example, if I had two tables, `communication` and `movement` that both have a columns named `ID` and `timestamp`, and I had a query that generally looked something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movement m
JOIN communication c 
ON m.ID = c.ID 
WHERE m.timestamp <= c.timestamp
ORDER BY abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,ctstamp,m.timestamp))
LIMIT 1;
```

This finds the closest `communication` timestamp for a given `movement` timestamp when `m.timestamp <= c.timestamp`, that is when the `movement timestamp` is less than the `communication timestamp`. But that leaves out all of `m.timestamp >= c.timestamp`.

What I want to do is create a range of like 10 seconds on either side, so that it would be:

```
WHERE m.timestamp BETWEEN c.timestamp-10 secs AND c.timestamp+10 secs
```

so if the `communication timestamp` was `'2012-03-02|09:02:30'`, then it would be:

```
WHERE m.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-03-02|09:02:20' AND '2012-03-02|09:02:40'
```

So how would I implement this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**EDIT**

In the end, I used this:

```
WHERE m.timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,-10,c.timestamp) 
AND TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,10,c.timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `interval` keyword:

```
WHERE m.timestamp BETWEEN c.timestamp - interval 10 second AND
                          c.timestamp + interval 10 second
```

Comment: Thanks! I would need to user `interval` in conjunction with [`timestampadd()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd), right? Kind of like what was in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793619/working-with-interval-and-curdate-in-mysql) question?