# SQL conditional SELECT with certain dates

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with selecting certain people from a table.

I need to select users from a table if they let's say didn't log in for 6 months.

But in the table we have older information as well. So if we write:

```
select * from dEmail where date < '2017-06-01'
```

and if user logged in recently it still selects him. I tried something like this:

```
select * from dEmail where date < '2017-06-01' and not date > '2017-06-01'
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe use curdate()?

Comment: Do you mean instead of date (which is declared in a table)? I will try it, but can't really see how this would work. Thanks.

Comment: It would be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793634/1821329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90c2c4)

The sql you are most likely looking for is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE LAST_LOGIN >= DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL - 6 MONTH);
```

Which will get all users that have not logged in for the last 6 months.