# How would I find records in the future

Tags: sql, mysql, date

If a slot is recurring it happens at the same time each week.

How would I fetch records scheduled later in the day, week, or month, considering the current date and time? I am using MySQL.

My current query is

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `timetable`
WHERE (`week` >= {$week} OR `recurring` = 1)
    AND `day` >= {$day}
    AND `hour` >= {$hour}
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: A datetime field `+ INTERVAL` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793619/working-with-interval-and-curdate-in-mysql  or one of the time functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Guessing day is a number 0-6 or 1-7; which is it and what day is the lowest?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you would want to include all weekly-recurring events, since there will always be one ahead of your current week/day/hour.  I also assume you would want all events that come after the current week, irrespective of the day, and within the current week, you would want all the events that come after the current day, irrespective of the hour.

If this is all correct, then your condition becomes:

```sql
WHERE `recurring` = 1
OR `week` >= {$week} AND (
    `week` > {$week}
    OR `day` >= {$day} AND (
        `day` > {$day}
        OR `hour` >= {$hour}
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Later in the day

```
SELECT *
FROM `timetable`
WHERE `recurring` = 1 AND
      DATE_ADD(`the_time`, INTERVAL 7 DAY) BETWEEN NOW() AND CAST(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS DATE)
```

Explanation:

- we search for recurring events
- we are interested in events between the current moment and the start of next day
- the start of next date is computed by adding a day to this moment and converting it to date
- I named your time column `the_time`, use yours instead of this one

## Later in the week

```
SELECT *
FROM `timetable`
WHERE `recurring` = 1 AND
      DATE_ADD(`the_time`, INTERVAL 7 DAY) BETWEEN NOW() AND CAST(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (7 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY) AS DATE)
```

Here the logic is the same, except for the end of the interval, where we add as many days as the number of days still left from the week. We add 7 for Monday, 6 for Tuesday, etc.

Now, `WEEKDAY` returns 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, etc.

So, 7 - WEEKDAY will result in the exact difference we want.

## Later in the Month

```
SELECT *
FROM `timetable`
WHERE `recurring` = 1 AND
      DATE_ADD(`the_time`, INTERVAL 7 DAY) BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Similar query, but with the start of the next month.

## General remarks

If you may have events at midnight, then you might want to subtract a second from the rightmost ends of the interval or use `<=` and `<` instead of `between`. I avoided those for the sake of understandability.

Also, this way you find recurring events, but you find them once. So, if you have a Friday night Karaoke each Friday night and it is scheduled to happen twice from the remainder of this month, this query will find it once.

If you want to show the recurring events for month view as many times they are scheduled for the month, you can use unioned queries or stored procedures.

Comment: Looks right to me, except that the limit 3 makes me think they want them in order, for which your want to join to a cte giving the range of dates of interest.

Comment: @ysth thanks for making that point. It's quite possible that the asker wants them in order and to limit the results. I did not order them because it was unclear to me whether that's the case, but you are correct that the query could end with `ORDER BY the_time LIMIT 0, 3`.